# I'm having trouble with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to make the display a diferent colour in pygame but the screen just stays black

this is the code i had for it:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo(1).png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False

screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
pygame.display.update()
```

I was following a tutorial on youtube but when i tried to make any colour it just stayed black.

Comment: *"I'm having trouble with pygame"* - is not an appropriate question. Please find a title that briefly describes the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry about that, i'll try not to do it next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I am following the same tutorial and you have to make sure that your `screen.fill` and `display.udpate` command are in your `while` loop at the right position under the `for` event like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo(1).png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False

  screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
  pygame.display.update()
```

Output:

[image]

The output should give you a blue background like above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the screen.fill((0, 0, 255)) and the pygame.display.update() are in the game loop (the `while running` loop).

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo(1).png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")

running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False

  screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
  pygame.display.update()
```

Also, if no action or animation is being display that would require the computer to do anything other than just loop through like normal, you can use the `pygame.event.wait()` method.

```
pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo(1).png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")

running = True
while running:
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
```